# Viewing all user metadata in user-edit.php or how to override

Tags: wordpress, metadata, edit

I have added some metadata into the account page of my users.

I want this data to be shown and editable in the `user-edit.php` page which shows user information.

I thought of modifying this file, but I later realized that if there is a WordPress update, this file would be overwritten.

How should I do this?

Comment: I found the solution by adding this to functions.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly simple, and it should be done alongside your code used to add the custom user profile field.

The below block of code will add the custom field to the user profile:

```
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'my_custom_user_profile_field' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'my_custom_user_profile_field' );
function my_custom_user_profile_field( $user ) { ?>
    <h3>Custom Field</h3>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="my-custom-user-profile-field">Input Label:</label></th>
            <td>
                <input name="my-custom-user-profile-field" id="my-custom-user-profile-field" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'my-custom-user-profile-field', $user->ID ) ); ?>" class="regular-text" type="text">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
<?php }
```

You will then need to ensure that the field(s) you have added can be saved. You can do this by hooking into `personal_options_update` and `edit_user_profile_update` like this:

```
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_my_custom_user_profile_field' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_my_custom_user_profile_field' );
function save_my_custom_user_profile_field( $user_id ) {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_user', $user_id ) )
        return false;
    update_user_meta( absint( $user_id ), 'my-custom-user-profile-field', wp_kses_post( $_POST['my-custom-user-profile-field'] ) );
}
```

Comment: I was just posting a solution, which was basically the same but using another php file and including it! Thanks!!!

Comment: Ah - well I am glad I saved you the hassle of using an external file :)